# Extract substring after second last colon

Tags: looker-studio

I am having a set of strings like this in a report field:

```
cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7

cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
```

I need to extract the words **after** the second last colon "**:**"

```
ie.cpe:/o:centos:centos:7 -> should transform as centos:7
  cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7 -> should transform as enterprise_linux:7
```

There are some regular expressions in like

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(string,[^\:]+$)
```

This gives me the last word after : but not the second last word.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following regex pattern:

```
[^:]+:[^:]+$
```

Updated code:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(string, [^:]+:[^:]+$)
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y96Wxp/1) showing that the pattern is working against your sample text.

Answer (score 1):

Added `"` `"` and a Capturing Group `(` `)` to the [Answer by Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64871312/12892553) to ensure that the [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) captures the required values:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(string, ":([^:]+:[^:]+)$")
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/88849c76-7dda-44c5-8423-dbe81121e86a) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]